# Optimize the query to display the total score of the student

Tags: mysql

Wrote a query for this small dataset to find the total score of students.

Conditions:

1. Display student total score (top scorer on the top).
2. If student gave an exam 2 time than pick the max score.
3. if student have max score less than 30 in any subject then remove from output .

**-- create**

```
CREATE TABLE Student (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  subject TEXT NOT NULL,
  marks int 
);
```

**-- insert**

```
INSERT INTO Student (name, subject, marks) VALUES ('Rahul', 'Math', 60);
INSERT INTO Student (name, subject, marks) VALUES ('Rahul', 'Science', 60);
INSERT INTO Student (name, subject, marks) VALUES ('Rahul', 'English', 29);
INSERT INTO Student (name, subject, marks) VALUES ('Rahul', 'English', 37);

INSERT INTO Student (name, subject, marks) VALUES ('Nitin', 'Science', 68);
INSERT INTO Student (name, subject, marks) VALUES ('Nitin', 'English', 69);
INSERT INTO Student (name, subject, marks) VALUES ('Nitin', 'Math', 73);


INSERT INTO Student (name, subject, marks) VALUES ('Naveen', 'Math', 60);
INSERT INTO Student (name, subject, marks) VALUES ('Naveen', 'Science', 20);
INSERT INTO Student (name, subject, marks) VALUES ('Naveen', 'English', 29);
INSERT INTO Student (name, subject, marks) VALUES ('Naveen', 'English', 87);
```

**-- fetch**

```
SELECT name, sum(score) as totalScore from (
  SELECT name, subject, max(marks) as score from Student where name not in (
    SELECT name from (
      SELECT name, subject, max(marks) as marks from Student group by name, subject
    ) as abc where marks < 30
  ) group by name, subject
) as f group by name order by totalScore DESC;
```

**--Output**

```
name    totalScore
Nitin   210
Rahul   157
```

Query mentioned gave correct output but curious to learn if there are any other ways to retrieve the correct output or whether we can optimise this query.

Comment: I guess your query wan't fullfil the 3 question. *Naveen* also has a max score geater than 30

Answer (score 0):

This is an other way to do it using `left join` :

First we need to identify students having max score less than 30 in any subject :

```
select name, subject, max(marks) as marks
from Student
group by name, subject
having max(marks) < 30
```

Then we will have to eliminate those students by performing a `left join` on this dataset `t` with a condition `t.name is null` :

```
select s.name, s.subject, max(s.marks) as maxSubjectScore
from Student s
left join (
  select name, subject, max(marks) as marks
  from Student
  group by name, subject
  having max(marks) < 30
) as t on s.name = t.name
where t.name is null
group by s.name, s.subject
```

Then we apply the aggregate function `sum()` to this dataset to get the expected data:

```
select name, sum(maxSubjectScore) as totalScore
from (
    select s.name, s.subject, max(s.marks) as maxSubjectScore
    from Student s
    left join (
      select name, subject, max(marks) as marks
      from Student
      group by name, subject
      having max(marks) < 30
    ) as t on s.name = t.name
    where t.name is null
    group by s.name, s.subject
) as s
group by name
order by totalScore DESC;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/vKBTnuI0)

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the maximum mark for each subject per Student and then use it to filter any Student who has a score of less than 30 to filter out and calculate the sum.

With a CTE

```
with StudentMarks as (
    -- Select all students with their maximum score for each subject
    select
        name,
        subject,
        max(marks) marks
    from
        Student
    group by
        name,
        subject
)
-- Select all students who have score more than 30 for all subjects
select
    name,
    sum(marks) marks
from
    StudentMarks
group by
    name
having
    min(marks) >= 30
order by
    marks desc;
```

Same thing without CTE

```
select
    name,
    sum(marks) marks
from
    (
        select
            name,
            subject,
            max(marks) marks
        from
            Student
        group by
            name,
            subject
    ) StudentMarks
group by
    name
having
    min(marks) >= 30
order by
    marks desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution without joins is to count subjects with lower marks and exclude the student after the aggregation if lower marks count > 0

```sql
SELECT name, SUM(IF(mark >= 30, 0, 1)) AS lower_marks_count, SUM(mark) AS total_mark
FROM (
    SELECT name, subject, MAX(marks) mark
    FROM Student
    GROUP BY name, subject
) t
GROUP BY name
HAVING lower_marks_count = 0
ORDER BY total_mark DESC
```

```
name    total_mark
Nitin   210
Rahul   157
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/BOyMoUJa)